# Java REST call using angularjs with param value

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I am trying to make REST call in java using angularjs-

Java Code:-

```
@GET
@Path("/getData/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public static String getData(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        //Operation 
}
```

AngularJs REST call-

```
var response = $http.get('/projName/rest/get/getData', {params: {id: id}});
```

But it's giving me exception-

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact, that you're trying to access different endpoint. Your endpoint listens for requests like:

```
projName/rest/get/getData/{id}
//e.g.
projName/rest/get/getData/1
```

but you're calling:

```
projName/rest/get/getData?id={id}
projName/rest/get/getData?id=1
```

Your code should be:

```
var response = $http.get('/projName/rest/get/getData/' + id);

@GET
@Path("/getData/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public static String getData(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        //Operation 
}
```

Comment: thnx for answer, I could not find out, @PathVariable annotation in javax.ws package?

Comment: @rish I updated my answer. I gave you the Spring approach first

Comment: thank you so much, I'll add something here after @PathParam key name should come, like @PathParam("id")